# Arduino vs Wemos Fan control

Tags: esp8266

I have a working fan control with the correct wiring that works with arduino.

I would like to change the arduino with a Wemos D1 mini board.

When I hook everything up. The fans are not activated.

The fan is driven by a 12v charger. And the irf540n cicruit powers that. They just share a common ground and the pwm pin D5

Is there something I need to know about the difference in both of them?

Below is the code, I've changed D5 in the code to 14.

Still nothing seems to work.

```
    #define fan D5

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("start");
  pinMode(fan, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(fan, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(fan, HIGH);

  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(fan, LOW);
}
```

Comment: Yes. The Wemos is 3.3V. Have you taken that into account with your circuit design?

Comment: What kind of Arduino did you use before? Arduino is a broad family of different boards with different chips

Comment: @Majenko I thought that didn't matter because the fan is driven by a 12v charger. And the irf540n cicruit powers that. They just share a common ground and the pwm pin D5

Comment: IRF540 is not a good choice. You want something that has a lower threshold voltage really.

Comment: Indeed just switched everything up with an Arduino and it works... @Majenko would a level bit shifter work for this? (pure out of interest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IRF540 is not suitable to be controlled by a 3.3V device because it has a gate-source-threshold voltage of 2-4V (that's the voltage at which the mosfet **starts** to conduct, but you need to be above that voltage). While this worked at 5V logic level on the arduino, the 3.3V are not enough to make the mosfet switch entirely.

A suitable mosfet has a threshold voltage below 1V. Also for a fan, you eon't need a big mosfet rated for 30A, a tiny one will do it.